# How to convert Strings to XAML-TextBlocks with HyperLinks within an MVVM Binding

Tags: regex, wpf, xaml, mvvm, hyperlink

I'm looking for a mechanism (a ValueConverter?) that converts strings via Regular Expressions to XAML and replaces certain sections to hyperlinks – similar to a Wiki-MarkUp or Textile. These strings are stored in an ObservableCollection that I'm showing a VirtualizingStackPanel.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

As an example:

```
"See [MainSection] for further instructions."
```

should become...

```
<TextBlick>
    See <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path}">
     MainSection</Hyperlink>for further instructions.
</TextBlock>
```

Is something like this possible?

Considerations:

- This needs to work with thousands of entries in the list, so list virtualization must not be broken.
- There could be more than one Link within a string.

Comment: Bevan Arps pointed out that  https://github.com/theunrepentantgeek/Markdown.XAML can do this: "The source includes TextToFlowDocumentConverter for exactly that; there's a Demo project that's included in the repo."

Comment: It's OK to post and accept your own answer @pixtur; you might want to change that comment into the official answer. Glad you like the library.

Comment: I first want to give it a try ;-) If I can get it to run, I will write a proper answer.